# How to set the tcp option timestamp while building a tcp SYN packet using python?

Tags: python, tcp, 32-bit

I need to send a tcp SYN packet with timestamp value in tcp option. Since tcp opts should be prepacked in 32-bit representation, can anyone brief me how to set the value in 32 bit packet representaion with a example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that pretty easily with [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). When defining your TCP layer, just use

```
TCP(flags='S', options=[('Timestamp', (TSval, 0))])
```

where TSval is your timestamp value. If you want to convert the resultant packet to its binary representation, call `str()` on it.

In future packets, you can replace the `0` with the appropriate TS echo reply per [RFC 1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323).