# Python and Windows add TCP timestamp to header

Tags: python, tcp, timestamp

I'm a real py and TCP novice but I need to send 18 to 141 bytes of data with the time stamp in the header. I saw this link

[How to set the tcp option timestamp while building a tcp SYN packet using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082516/how-to-set-the-tcp-option-timestamp-while-building-a-tcp-syn-packet-using-python)

but I will be working with windows 7 and I have no idea where to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch on TCP timestamping, it's a TCP option under Windows.  Have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938205.aspx?ppud=4

Set Tcp1323Opts to 2 in the registry, reboot and timestamps are switched on on all outgoing connections (assuming the other side supports them as well).

But why do you want that?  You have no access to the timestamps from an application, they are only there to aid TCP with long fat networks and large TCP windows.